# Can I Find/Search in Sublime Text with multiple cursor / multiple selection?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way to do a "find next" or "incremental search" when you have multiple selections/cursors in Sublime Text? For example, let's say I'm trying to edit several lines below:

```
$array[] = array('id' => 1, 'label' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'); //test test test
$array[] = array('id' => 2, 'label' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit'); //test test
$array[] = array('id' => 3, 'label' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor'); //test
```

If I need to update all 3 of those lines, I can easily move around with arrows and option-arrows to go from word to word... but when I get to the "labels", I want to advance ALL of my multiple cursors to the end of the string... but since each string is a different length, I am unable to do so. If I were able to do something like "find the next occurrence of ",);" across ALL selections", then it would be really easy. But I can't seem to find a way to perform such an operation on multiple cursors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple cursors and the "Expand Selection to Scope" command to do this.

Start by putting a cursor in each of the labels, either by Cmd/Ctrl+clicking or clicking in the first label and choosing `Selection > Add Next Line` from the menu. Repeat for as many labels as you have.

Then, choose `Selection > Expand Selection to Scope` from the menu. This will expand the selection of each cursor to the beginning through ending of the label. This will also select the quotes, so make sure you requote the string when you type the new one.

**Note**: This will only work with a syntax that defines a quoted string. Not sure which language your example is, but this method worked for C++ and C#, but not plain text. Plain text expanded the selection to the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip, and especially the explanation about how the language syntax defines what a "scope" is. My example is in php, but I often require this technique in other languages too. It's not exactly perfect in all situations but does work sometimes (which is better than never). I find it odd that for all of Sublime's flexibility, there are some things related to searches that don't interact well with macros or multiple selections.

Answer (score -1):

In this case I hit the END key to go to the end of the line and then back arrow.

Or hold shift and hit the end key to select to the end of the line.

---

In the case described in the comments what I typically do is use the search functionality combined with regular expressions to select the section I want.

So in your example I would simply construct a regex and then use replace for find all to select them.

> (as an aside, there was an editor in a time long ago that did as you
>   describe called brief.  Sadly that editor is lost to corporate
>   takeovers.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not address the situation I'm asking about. Look closely at the example text I have... see how the comments are different length? This is the situation I sometimes find myself in, where you cannot just go to the END of the line and then back, but rather you want to go to a certain "token" or delineation within each line _that might be a different string or word length_.